# Clojure / core.matrix / initialize 2d array

Tags: clojure

In clojure a 2-d array can be initialized with a value like so:

```
(defn vec2d
  "Return an x by y vector with all entries equal to val."
  [x y val]
  (vec (repeat y (vec (repeat x val)))))
```

Is there maybe a core.matrix built-in feature that would do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`new-matrix`](https://mikera.github.io/core.matrix/doc/clojure.core.matrix.html#var-new-matrix) and [`fill`](https://mikera.github.io/core.matrix/doc/clojure.core.matrix.html#var-fill):

```
(require '[clojure.core.matrix :as matrix])

(defn vec2d
  "Return an x by y vector with all entries equal to val."
  [x y val]
  (matrix/fill (matrix/new-matrix y x) val))
```

If you need the result to be a regular 2D Clojure vector, you can call [`to-nested-vectors`](https://mikera.github.io/core.matrix/doc/clojure.core.matrix.html#var-to-nested-vectors) on the result. At that point, though, you're probably better off just using the original solution from your question.

Comment: Isn't new-matrix producing regular nested clojure vectors anyways? I discovered, that the following returns true: (let [mat (m/new-matrix 2 2)] (= (m/to-nested-vectors mat)) mat))

Comment: @AntonHarald Yes, but `fill` does not.